# How to import packages in monorepo within Go service?

Tags: git, go, monorepo

I have a monorepo. Let's say it's `github.com/myself/monorepo`. I have two services in it: `service-one` and `service-two`. Each has a `go.mod` file.

In `service-one` I have a type to import:

```golang
package service-one

type StructOne {

}
```

And I'm importing it from `service-two`:

```golang
package service-two

import pack "github.com/myself/monorepo/service-one"

func MyFunc() {
    var v pack.StructOne
}
```

In `service-two` `go.mod` file I tried two options:

To refer temporary commit on a branch:

```golang
require github.com/myself/monorepo/service-one 38e00c33c01a9ac17c177ba25e9764c4d1c1310f
```

To refer a tagged commit on `master`

```golang
require github.com/myself/monorepo/service-one v0.0.0
```

Both times I get an error like:

```
 not found: github.com/myself/monorepo/service-one@v0.0.0 invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/...
   fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

How should I arrange repository correctly? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

If this is a private repository, you should:

1. Set `GOPRIVATE=github.com/myself/monorepo` so that it won't try to download from the proxy server.
2. Make sure `git` doesn’t require a password to be entered interactively. For example, use a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) to store the credential.

But before that, ask yourself why you want to create two modules. If there is not a good reason, create a single module that containing multiple packages instead.

If you have to go with multiple modules, utilize the workspace to ease local development. See [Tutorial: Getting started with multi-module workspaces](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces).

And please note that a module defined in a subdirectory within the repository is tagged differently. See [Mapping versions to commits](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-version):

> If a module is defined in a subdirectory within the repository, that is, the module subdirectory portion of the module path is not empty, then each tag name must be prefixed with the module subdirectory, followed by a slash. For example, the module golang.org/x/tools/gopls is defined in the gopls subdirectory of the repository with root path golang.org/x/tools. The version v0.4.0 of that module must have the tag named gopls/v0.4.0 in that repository.

There is another issue in your question:

> require github.com/myself/monorepo/service-one 38e00c33c01a9ac17c177ba25e9764c4d1c1310f

You should not put commit id into the `go.mod` file manually like this. Run the following commands and the Go tool will translate it into a pseudo-version and updated `go.mod` for you. See [Pseudo-versions](https://go.dev/ref/mod#pseudo-versions):

- `go get github.com/myself/monorepo/service-one@38e00c33c01a9ac17c177ba25e9764c4d1c1310f`
- or `go get github.com/myself/monorepo/service-one@master`

Comment: Finally I found that I had GOPROXY and GONOSUMDB set up with my old job's values ))) Thanks for a hint!